# Sorting NSMutableDictonary on Value AND Key?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray, nsmutabledictionary

I am trying to sort and NSMutableDictionary by value first, then by key.  I have the sort by value working with the code below:

```
       NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithCapacity:10];
        [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5] forKey:@"eblk"];
        [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:@"dstl"];
        [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:4] forKey:@"cast"];
        [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:4] forKey:@"breb"];
        [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5] forKey:@"apts"];

         NSArray *sortedKeys = [dict keysSortedByValueUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) 
        {
          if ([obj1 integerValue] < [obj2 integerValue]) {
              return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
          }
          if ([obj1 integerValue] > [obj2 integerValue]) {
              return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
          }
          return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
        }];
```

I then want to sort again based on key so I end up with an array of keys like this:

sortedKeys : corresponding value in dict

"apts":        5

"eblk":      5

"breb":     4

"cast":        4

"dstl":        2

I have the first sort on value working, I'm just not sure how to get started on the secondary sort based on key.

I tried sorting it by key first then by value, but that didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to sort a dictionary?  A dictionary is an unordered collection, so even if you sort the keys or the values, they won't necessarily be in that order if you log the dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do is a two key sort. For any n-key sort you compare the keys in order, returning a result if the current pair are not equal otherwise move onto the next pair of keys and repeat.

Outline sketch for your two keys:

1. Get an array of the keys so you can sort them
2. Sort that array using a two key sort:

   - Get the values by looking them up
   - Compare values and return if not equal
   - Compare keys;

Code sketch:

```
NSArray *allKeys = [dict allKeys];
NSArray *sortedKeys = [allKeys sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2)
{
   NSInteger value1 = [[dict objectForKey:obj1] integerValue];
   NSInteger value2 = [[dict objectForKey:obj2] integerValue];

   if (value1 < value2) 
      return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
   if (value1 > value2) 
      return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
   // values are equal, compare keys...         
   return [obj1 compare:obj2];
}];
```

Comment: The exact solution I needed.  Thank you.